# recuperate USABLE space NEXUS 5

Tags: ubuntu-touch

the question how to restore the full capacity of the disk space on my Nexus 5. Mine default disk space is 32 GB, but after I installed ubuntu touch and then returned original ROM my disk space is no longer 32 gigabytes, and now is a 26.7 gigabytes. How to restore its 32 gigabytes? I tried all the recommendations described in the Instruction, but it does not work. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### That is the Actual Usable space.

There is a difference between the manufacturer's unit of measurement of size. That and the system has to use space as well.

A Picture of my Nexus 5, and Ubuntu touch has never been installed.

[image]